# How to parse this json object into Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm working with requests, and I got stucked, because I'm changing my source. Thing is, when I request the object to the website, it returns the following json object:

```
[
{
"directory":"ca\/48",
"hash":"ca4860af9e3be43b1d23b823af607be4",
"height":1839,
"id":3461818,
"image":"ca4860af9e3be43b1d23b823af607be4.jpg",
"change":1480968006,
"owner":"danbooru",
"parent_id":null,
"rating":"s",
"sample":true,
"sample_height":1398,
"sample_width":850,
"score":0,
"tags":"1girl breasts cape cleavage defense_of_the_ancients dota_2 green_eyes highres lyralei medium_breasts parted_lips pauldrons red_hair smile solo splashbrush thick_thighs thighs toes",
"width":1118,
 "file_url":"http:\/\/gelbooru.com\/images\/ca\/48\/ca4860af9e3be43b1d23b823af607be4.jpg"
}
]
```

And I want to change the `"file_url"` value from `"http:\/\/gelbooru.com\/images\/ca\/48\/ca4860af9e3be43b1d23b823af607be4.jpg"`

to

`"http://gelbooru.com/images/ca/48/ca4860af9e3be43b1d23b823af607be4.jpg"`
so I'll be able to use the website fully by calling it on my program's builder.
How do I do that?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are probably hundreds of similar questions. Pleas do some research before posting something that is likely a duplicate.

Comment: "json object" is not quite a thing in Python. You have a list with a single item, which is a dict. If you know how to modify a dict and access a list element, you will find the rest.

Comment: `requests` can convert JSON to python dictionary/list - `response.json` - and it can convert `\/` to correct text.

Comment: @bereal Thing is, I need the full link, so I'll be able to work with it

Comment: @furas I'll try

Comment: Oh wait, are you asking about those `\/\/` things? They are not a part of the string, it's a part of its representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests` can automatically convert JSON data to python dictionary/list

```
r = request.get(...)

data = r.json()
```

and then you have access

```
print( data[0]['file_url'] )
```

and you will see that there is no `\/` because it was converted to correct text.

---

Example with standard `json` module which is used by `requests` internally.

```
text = '''[
{
"directory":"ca\/48",
"hash":"ca4860af9e3be43b1d23b823af607be4",
"height":1839,
"id":3461818,
"image":"ca4860af9e3be43b1d23b823af607be4.jpg",
"change":1480968006,
"owner":"danbooru",
"parent_id":null,
"rating":"s",
"sample":true,
"sample_height":1398,
"sample_width":850,
"score":0,
"tags":"1girl breasts cape cleavage defense_of_the_ancients dota_2 green_eyes highres lyralei medium_breasts parted_lips pauldrons red_hair smile solo splashbrush thick_thighs thighs toes",
"width":1118,
 "file_url":"http:\/\/gelbooru.com\/images\/ca\/48\/ca4860af9e3be43b1d23b823af607be4.jpg"
}
]'''

import json

data = json.loads(text)

print( data[0]['file_url'] )
```